# Retrieve Lists of Kernels from a Python Script

Tags: python, jupyter

I am trying to retrieve a list of installed kernels in a virtual environment from within a Python script that runs in a different virtual environment. Usually, in the console, I use `jupyter kernelspec list` from the virtual environment that I am interested in. But I don't get this to work within a Python script.

What I tried:

```
import subprocess
from pathlib import Path

env1 = Path(r'C:\virtualenvs\my_env\Scripts\python.exe')
env2 = Path(r'C:\virtualenvs\jupyter_env\Scripts\python.exe')
jupyter1 = Path(r'C:\virtualenvs\my_env\Scripts\jupyter.exe')
jupyter2 = Path(r'C:\virtualenvs\jupyter_env\Scripts\jupyter.exe')

packages1 = subprocess.run([env1, '-m', 'pip', 'list'],
                           stdout=subprocess. PIPE)
print(packages1.stdout.decode('utf-8'))

packages2 = subprocess.run([env2, '-m', 'pip', 'list'],
                           stdout=subprocess. PIPE)
print(packages2.stdout.decode('utf-8'))

kernels1 = subprocess.run([jupyter1, 'kernelspec', 'list'],
                          stdout=subprocess. PIPE)
print(kernels1.stdout.decode('utf-8'))

kernels2 = subprocess.run([jupyter2, 'kernelspec', 'list'],
                          stdout=subprocess. PIPE)
print(kernels2.stdout.decode('utf-8'))
```

I execute this script from within `my_env`. The result is:

```
Package                       Version
----------------------------- ---------
asteval                       0.9.27
...
zipp                          3.8.1

Package              Version
-------------------- -----------
anyio                3.6.1
...
websocket-client     1.3.3

Available kernels:
  python3    C:\virtualenvs\my_env\share\jupyter\kernels\python3

Available kernels:
  python3    C:\virtualenvs\my_env\share\jupyter\kernels\python3
```

The calls `pip list` give me the result from the respective environments irrespective of the environment that runs the script. However, the `kernelspec` calls show the kernels of the environment I am executing from (`my_env`) in both cases.

**Question A:** How can I make sure the last of the `subprocess` calls is executed within the `jupyter_env`?

or

**Question B:** How can I get the list of kernels from a specific virtual environment from a Python script (maybe there is a solution that does not involve `subprocess` calls)?

I'm using Python 3.10.3 and jupyter-core 4.11.1 in both environments.